# Make an element scroll inside a grid section

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make a scrollable area inside my div like the image below. I want only the scrollable area to change height on different screen heights and scrolls accordingly.

[image: Design]

The problem, is if the scrollable content is big enough to scroll, it will make the whole page scroll. If its small, the footer stays at the bottom correctly.

Here is a what I have so far

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.profile {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.tabs {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.scroller {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scrollable-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">Header</div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="profile">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-control">
      <div class="tabs">Tabs</div>
      <div class="scroller">
        <div class="scrollable-content">scrollable content<span>end</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>

</div>
```

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you set some elements to have `overflow: hidden;`. Set that for `.container`, `.content`, and `.tab-control`

```css
.container, .content, .tab-control {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You will have a small issue with the `.scroller` element, part of it will be covered by the footer.

To fix that, add this too:

```css
.tab-control {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scroller {
  flex: 100% 1 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed height on scroller. 100vh = height of the browser - 140px (the cumulative height of all the other elements on the page)

Set overflow-y: auto on the bar you want to scroll and you can set the height of .scrollable-content to as big as you want.

```
.scroller {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: calc(100vh - 140px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scrollable-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: but see, if any of the other elements change height, the scroller will need to be updated everytime too.

Comment: I don't understand why that's a problem, if a different element changes height, then update it accordingly in the .scroller class, or better yet, adjust for the height of the scroller class after you finished the design for all elements above it. If you're looking for a solution to update the .scoller dynamically based on content changes, then use javascript.

Comment: Css Grid should be able to automatically determine the scroller height as the container is 100vh. This solution is right without grid but grid makes it so you dont have to update multiple places and detects automaticly. im not sure why my example of grid isnt working